# Initialize h:selectOneMenu before it is shown

Tags: jsf, initialization, postconstruct

I have the access page where I check for a valid user, if it exists then pass to the next page and create a

```
String[] options;
```

based on the typeOfUser. So if user is type-A the options should be:

```
String[] options = {"1","2","3"};
```

if user is type-B, options should be:

```
String[] options = {"1","2"};
```

in any other case, options should be:

```
String[] options = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

and in the xhtml page is as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="option">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.options}>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

can I achieve this in the @PostConstruct method? or is there a better place.

Thanks !

Comment: I was doing it right. In the @PostConstruct method, I could initialize the `options` variable and populate the selectOneMenu with the correct options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it right. In the @PostConstruct method, I could initialize the options variable and populate the selectOneMenu with the correct options.